# htaccess rewrite to secure folder path

Tags: security, .htaccess, url-rewriting, subdirectory

I have an application in a folder that I want to keep hidden. Instead I want to be able to access the folder from a secret path, for example:

Current path: example.com/myfolder

Change path to myfolder.example.com

When someone visits example.com/myfolder I just want it to return page not found.

I then want to make the new path accessible only from my IP. Have tried various methods but having no success. Any suggestions/examples would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

1st you can use htaccess hide your floder, put this code inside of the folder (the folder you want to hide), allow from is for your ip

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from 127.0.0.1 (your ip)
```

2nd use htaccess set up password

```
AuthName "Private zone"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /pub/home/your_login/.htpasswd
require valid-user

.htpasswd (make anther file for pw)
your username:your password
```

3rd
www.example.com/myfolder->www.myfolder.example.com
something.example.com this is sub domain

it will become

```
public_html/all your files and floder
something/others files
```

read this one will help
http://www.htpasswdgenerator.com/apache/htaccess.html